# why plugin blocked by Safari?

Tags: javascript, plugins, safari, block

My plugin almost works fine in Safari for Mac, but sometimes it is blocked by Safari(see at Safari - Preferences - Security - Manage website setttings).

so my first question is how can I let my plugin be a "Allow Always" plugin in Safari without user's operation?

And when plugin is blocked, Safari will display a placeholder instead of the Internet plugin content. [look here](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202819)

so the second question is when Safari block my plugin(maybe user choosed), how to know it by JS?

Comment: What version of Safari are you using to load your plugin?  And does your plugin require any external software like Flash?

Comment: Hi Max. Safari's version is 8.0.2 , and the plugin run independently. Did you have some advices?

Comment: Is the `Allow Always` option not available for your plugin at all?

Comment: No, it just be blocked  sometimes . When this happen, it would work fine if user chooses  "Allow Always" option . But it is difficult for user to fine the settings. So I want to know can I let my plugin be a "Allow Always" plugin in Safari without user's operation? Or can JS know plugin is blocked by Safari?

Comment: You don't have any control of the security settings for the plugin from inside the plugin otherwise that would completely break the browser security model and make the user settings obsolete/useless and also introduce a security vulnerability (imagine if malicious plugins that were blocked could turn themselves back on!).  If the plugin is blocked then the plugin will never be executed and your code will be completely ignored (otherwise the user setting to block the plugin would not be honored and also become useless).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Maybe my first question is foolish~ Hope someone can help me about the second question. Max, thanks a lot !

Comment: I actually answered both of your questions in my answer.  If the user has chosen to block your plugin or the browser has blocked your plugin then no part of your plugin should be executed at all therefore you will not have a way to know (inside your plugin using JS) that your plugin was blocked because your plugin is never executed.  What you are trying to do is impossible because of the security mechanisms in place by Safari.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand what I mean in my question. When the plugin is blocked, I wish JS to know and then show some tips to user, like "please click here to allow the plugin to run". Thanks for you patient !

Comment: No I don't misunderstand your question but I think you are misunderstanding my answer.  If your plugin is blocked *no code inside your plugin will be run* (because it is blocked from running).  If you can still execute JavaScript in your plugin when the plugin is blocked then that would be a security risk and defeat the purpose of blocking a plugin.  So once again - when your plugin is blocked all of the JavaScript inside your plugin is ignored making it impossible to accomplish a "please click here to allow the plugin to run" function.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing browser behavior from plugin behavior.  Sometimes the browser will alert the user that a plugin is blocked giving them the option to reenable the plugin if they so choose. However that functionality is *not* coming from the plugin itself (because it is blocked and can't run any JavaScript code at all).

Comment: Hi Max, it’s my fault that you misunderstood my words. I mean the JavaScript in my website, not inside my plugin, . Since I know plugin can do nothing when it is blocked, I wander that is it possible for JavaScript to know. And then my website can show some tips~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comments above made it more clear what you were trying to accomplish.  It has already been established that if your plugin is blocked than no code inside your plugin will be executed (for security reasons) but it is possible to let your website know if the plugin was loaded (or not loaded) using [injected scripts](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/InjectingScripts/InjectingScripts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH6-SW1).  [Here is an example](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH14-SW2) on the Apple developer page showing how an injected script can access a JavaScript function.

[In this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/ExtensionPermissions/ExtensionPermissions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH8-SW1) you will find everything you need to know about access and restrictions for your plugins and extensions

And [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH14-SW1) will help you understand messaging and proxying between different components of your plugin and the website.